# Excel Formula to count all cells that only contain a single date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column that contains text, nothing, a single date in 0/0/0000 format, multiple dates, or text and a single date or multiple dates.

I am looking to count the number of cells that only contain a single date.  I don't think I can use a regex in excel, so I am not sure how to go about this.

I tried to see if I could count the number of cells with a date above 1900 but that didn't work.

```
=COUNTIF(O:O,">1/1/1900")
```

For example:

```
chicago
chicago,1/5/2014
1/6/2015
Time to call,Text1

12/5/2010
12/6/2010,12/8/2010
```

I would want a count of 2 as rows 3 and 6 are the only two rows that contain a single date.

Comment: no other numbers but dates?

Comment: is the date a number formatted to display text, or is the date an actual string?

Comment: The date is an actual string and there are no other numbers but dates.

Comment: you may want to change your test to `countif(O:O,">"&date(1900,1,1))`

Comment: Are you trying to do it in the same column?  Are you getting a circular reference error?  If so, reference the cells by # too (ex. O2:O11)

Comment: The formula with &date didn't make a difference for me.  I am putting the formula in a different column and not getting an error.  ISNUMBER wouldn't help me with cells that have two dates or text and a date unfortunately.  I need to count only cells with a single date.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question but can you please try: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(A:Z)))` ?

Comment: Can you provide some excel data so we can reproduce the issue in excel?

Comment: Sure, see question.

Comment: `=COUNTIF(O:O;">=32874")` There's actually even simpler version of what I did before.

Comment: Seems to work on the sample data as well

Comment: That worked on the sample data (aside from changing the semicolon to a comma) but when I put the sample data in excel, it shows the date as date type.  In my real data, i see now the dates are showing as general type.  Now I need to figure out how to convert those to a date type it appears.

Comment: It should be irrelevant in this case, it should work even for the text format actually

Comment: You should check if the data is not "stored as text" though

Comment: I tried formatting the column to text type and the formula doesn't work for me.  Returns 0.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/convert-numbers-stored-as-text-to-numbers-40105f2a-fe79-4477-a171-c5bad0f0a885 As I said format should be irrelevant this is what I'm talking about

Comment: If I create a new sheet, it works fine but not on my original data that has 800k rows.  I'll try to figure it out.  If you want to add yours as an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok just try one more thing for me please, select the O column in the original, Go to Home - Find and Select - Replace and replace all / with / , this is a workaround for few problems that I sometimes use in my VBA apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you make sure that data isn't [stored as text](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/convert-numbers-stored-as-text-to-numbers-40105f2a-fe79-4477-a171-c5bad0f0a885), you can use one of these as your data doesn't include numbers that aren't dates.

```
=COUNTIF(O:O;">=1")
```

Where 1 is a numeric value for 1.1.1900

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(A:Z)))
```

This sumproduct checks whether the data is numeric however it doesn't include the >1900 condition.

Comment: I think you meant 1990, not 1900.

Answer (score 0):

=SUMPRODUCT(1-ISERR(DATEVALUE(O:O)))

Comment: Cover both true dates and text-that-look-like-dates with `=SUMPRODUCT(1-ISERR(DATEVALUE(TEXT(O:O, "mm/dd/yyyy;@"))))`.

Comment: @Jeeped That's actually probably the best answer for the question

Comment: I agree. Better than assuming it's all text.